# Clang-tidy check like LLVMHeaderGuardCheck but for configurable include paths?

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

Anyone know of any sources for a `LLVMHeaderGuardCheck` like clang-tidy check that formats the expected include guards based on configurable information like the include path(s) given on the command line?

More details...

The `LLVMHeaderGuardCheck` header guard check expects header file include guard macro names that are all uppercase letters of the path after `include/` with the `/` replaced by `_` and a suffix like `.h` or `.hpp` replaced with `_H`. That works as a fine header guard check so long as your header files are all under a common root that has `include/` in its path.

What I'm looking instead for is a check which works based on the path given in a `-I$path` command line argument. So if given an include file path like `-I/usr/local/xyz` an include file named `/usr/local/xyz/common/foo.h` needs to have include guard of `XYZ_COMMON_FOO_H`.

I wrote [some code](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/clang-tools-extra/pull/1/commits/ff06cd79a18231904ebab255f5e3286013c63f01) to work for the meantime but my commit only uses the path as an option from the `.clang-tidy` configuration file. While this suffices, it's not as flexible as a solution that can also use the command line info.

So I'm wondering what else is out there as open source checks for clang-tidy for header file include guard naming checks as I haven't had any luck finding anything via the web searching I've done to-date.